# Assembly correct usage of word/byte/word ptr

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I'm writing a little machine code generator for assembly. I have a question regarding immediate to memory instructions:

Let's take these 3 scenarios:

```
add [ebx+04], 0x1
add [ebx+04], 0x4040
add [ebx+04], 0x401000
```

What I do is going by the immediate constant, I check what is the smallest number of bytes it can fit in then I assume whether its byte ptr, word ptr, dword ptr

First one can fit in 1 byte so I assume it to be:

```
add byte ptr [ebx+04], 0x1
```

Second can fit in 2 bytes so I assume it to be:

```
add word ptr [ebx+04], 0x4040
```

third fits in 4 bytes so I assume it to be:

```
add dword ptr [ebx+04], 0x401000
```

Is this correct?

Comment: No.  How do you expect to generate a 32-bit add of 1?  The PTR annotation is there for a reason.

Comment: there is a reason for the byte ptr, word ptr, etc nomenclature.  Because the user needs to be able to select which instruction/operand.  If you are making up your own you could instead use addb, addw, addd instead of x ptr.

Comment: if add [ebx+04], 0x00000001 produces a dword ptr, then maybe you can get away with it, if the users understand the rules for your assembly language.

Comment: Stating the obvious: the effect of adding 1 to a byte in memory is different from the effect of adding 1 to a dword in memory. In the latter case, carry (if any) goes over up to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most definitely need to accept size tags on these kind of instructions.

But I wouln't dismiss the code to see what numbers fit, because you will need a way to decide on the possibiliy to use a smaller encoding based on sign extending a byte:

```
add dword ptr [ebx+4], 1
```

This can be encoded with a 4 byte immediate, but also more interestingly with a 1 byte immediate.

Comment: I had another question, i'm aware you can sign extend 8 bit value to 32 bits using the bit. Does it apply for 16bit to 32bit too?

Comment: The x86 architecture defines that this _s-bit_ sign extends a byte into a word when the operand size is 16-bit, and that it extends a byte into a dword when the operand size is 32-bit. This clearly excludes sign-extending from 16-bit into 32-bit.

Answer (score 3):

If you also implement a way to explicitly specify the operand size, and since it's your assembler, it's ultimately your call to allow or not such "smart" deduction.

I strongly advice against it, programmers don't chose operand size based on the immediate values, but rather choose the immediates based on the operand size.
Simply put, we consider `add DWORD [ebx+04h], 1` and `add WORD [ebx+04h], 1` two completely separate instructions.